# Angular 5 - google map not visible in ng-bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, google-maps, modal-dialog, angular5, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to display a location using google map inside ng-bootstrap modal but some how map is not visible. if i put google map outside the modal its visible. I have read angular 5 and google map integration from [this url](https://blog.cloudboost.io/integrating-google-maps-in-angular-5-ca5f68009f29)

How to achieve this scenario of showing google map inside the modal?

this is template code

```
<button (click)="ver(mymodal)"> <button>
<ng-template #mymodal let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">{{temptask.name}}</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      <div #gmap style="width:100%;height:400px"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

component code:

```
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { } from '@types/googlemaps';
 @ViewChild('gmap') gmapElement: any;
  map: google.maps.Map;
ngOnInit() {

    var mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.5793, 73.8143),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, mapProp);
    this.map.fitBounds
}

ver( modal) {
    this.modalService.open(modal);

  }
```

Comment: can you provide a codepin link or something ?

Comment: Do you initialise map in hidden div? If so, you should trigger resize once the modal div is visible:  `google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, 'resize');`